# How to split a string of fix width using GDI +?

Tags: c#, gdi+

I have a big string that has got comma and new line character, i need to draw this string in a panel of fix width i want to take off each time string of length of panel width so that i can draw each string from new line.

```
foreach (btnObject custItem in this.lstDeniedCustomization)
{
    basketItemDescription = basketItemDescription + custItem.BtnName + ", ";                     
}
```

the basketitemdescription holds the string that i need to break of equal width of panel width.

I was trying with this..

```
 System.Drawing.SizeF mySize = g.MeasureString(basketItemDescription, this.Font); //get the size of the text property
 float stringHeight = mySize.Height;
 this.Height = mySize.Height;
```

but it gives me just the width and height of whole string while i need to draw it in a panel of some fixed width while the height need to fix at run time.

Comment: i want to get the string when i provide it the width to a method..

Comment: could some body help me with this...

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this overload to `Graphics.DrawString()`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19sb1bw6.aspx

It allows you to specify a rectangle in which the text is drawn so you don't have to split it yourself. An example can also be found at that page.